# Difference between "int[] myArray" and "int myArray[]" in Java

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between int[] array and int array[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

I've wondered for a long time whether or not there is a difference between the following:

```
int[] myArray;
```

and,

```
int myArray[];
```