# What is the preferred way to declare a Java array?

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between int[] array and int array[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

What is the difference between these two declarations of an array of native types in Java?

```
double items[] = new double[10];

double[] items = new double[10];
```

If they are the same is there any reason to prefer one over the other?