# Declaring arrays

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the preferred way to declare a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587584/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-declare-a-java-array)
>   [Difference between int[] array and int array[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

Hi!

Been learning Java for Android by reading some tutorials.  And in lots of the tutorials there are used two different ways of declaring arrays - even in the same project:

```
public int integers[] = { ... };

public int[] integers = { ... };
```

Does it matter or are these two basically the same?