# Difference between public static void main(String[] args) and public static void main(String args[])?

Tags: java, string, program-entry-point, void

I am newbie In Java programming language. There are various tutorials for beginners about Java basics. I saw some of them there `public static void main(String[] args)` function and the same time i have seen  `public static void main(String args[])` function. What is difference between public static void main(String[] args) and public static void main(String args[])?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Another dupe: [Java Array Declaration Bracket Placement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103666/java-array-declaration-bracket-placement).

Comment: Thank you very much. really duplicated

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will both function the same. There is no difference between the two, aside from personal preference.