# Java Syntax: byte f()[] vs. byte[] f()

Tags: java, syntax

Just noticed in `ByteArrayOutputStream`, the `toByteArray()` is declared as,

```
public synchronized byte toByteArray()[];
```

What's the difference between this declaration and the following one?

```
public synchronized byte[] toByteArray();
```

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array

Comment: Not a dup, the horrible syntax for array return types is new here. I wouldn't have imagined this could be legal Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, none.

If you had declarations:

```
byte[] a, b;
byte c[], d;
```

then `a`, `b`, and `c` are `byte[]`, and `d` is `byte`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, though convention amongst programmers strongly prefers the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Java coding conventions document recommends the second variant (byte[] b). See [example](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc10.html).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, for multidimensional arrays you can also mix both approaches:

```
public synchronized byte[] to2DByteArray()[];
```

Comment: Well that is the path down the the hell of confusion :/