# java array declaration

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between int[] array and int array[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

In Java, we can declare an array in these two styles:

```
int a[];
int []b;
```

Is there any difference?