# Difference between type[] varName and type varName[]?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

Is there any difference between delaring an array like

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

and declaring it like

```
int array[] = new int[10];
```

?

Both are valid in Java but I havent found any differences (initialization or something?) or is it just two different ways to describe the same thing for the compiler?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846080/java-array-declaration

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They have no difference, but that notational difference allows this identity:

```
int[] array; int[][] matrix;
```

===

```
int array[], matrix[][];
```

===

```
int[] array, matrix[];
```

Here is the related specification page:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#17235

Comment: @Vitalii - lol you scared me; for a second I thought you were serious

Answer (score 2):

`int array[]` is the way C people do it, `int[] array` is the preferred syntax for Java.  The functionality in either case is identical.

This is a good article about java coding style issues: [Speaking the Java Language without an accent](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-noaccent.html?ca=drs-#N102E6)

Answer (score 1):

They both do the same thing.