# Array declaration in Java

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between int[] array and int array[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

Is `int[] arr;` functionally the same as `int arr[];`?

Comment: Even more entertainingly, try: public int getIntArray()[].

Comment: i feel int arr[] is worse: int[] arr follows TYPE VAR_NAME style, whereas int arr[] is more like TY VAR_NAME PE

Comment: I find it amusing that what could easily have been written as a subjective question (which is better?) wasn't, and then it gets subjective answers and comments.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can put the braces in either place when declaring an array.

Bonus: you can even put 'em here:
`int []arr`

Comment: +1. Also see http://www.ibiblio.org/java/course/week2/47.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the functionality is the same. You can have the braces anywhere.

```
int[] a,b,c[];
```

is equivalent to

```
int a[],b[],c[][];
```

Comment: I hope you don't really write int[] c[]; in your own code!

Comment: Yea, sure I wont. It's just to show the possibility and semantics.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the matter of style. You can pick the style you like. They perform exactly the same. Some claim that if you write "int[] array", it will be clearer that it's an array of integer rather than writing "int array[]".

Answer (score 0):

It is, it's just to appease C++ developers they include int arr[]. (Or at least what I told in school)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's the same. int[] arr is more convenient though.