# java - Array brackets after variable name

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between int[] array and int array[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

I saw this example in a java tutorial:

```
private int puzzle[];
```

This is different to the 'normal' declaration type I'm familiar with:

```
private int[] puzzle;
```

eclipse accepts both. Is there a difference between these 2 notations?