# Passing an array to a Java function

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java - Array brackets after variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521891/java-array-brackets-after-variable-name)

When writing a Java function that accepts an array as a parameter, should the function  definition have the brackets ("[]") on the type or the variable name?

As in:

```
private int myFunction(int array[])
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

or...

```
private int myFunction(int[] array)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

They both "work", but is there a technical difference between the two?

Comment: You can also do `private int myFunction(int... array)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no difference.  But `int[] array` is considered idiomatic Java.

The logic is that `[]` is part of the type (an array is a distinct type from a scalar), and so `int` and `[]` should live together.  It's also consistent with the notation for e.g. return types:

```
int[] foo() {
    ...
    int[] x = new int[5];
    return x;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK int foo()[]{} is also valid, so both would be consistent with return types.

Comment: @josefx: That may well be true.  But if I saw someone write `int foo()[]` in real code, I'd have to spank them.

Answer (score 2):

When there is single variable it doesn't make much difference, however when its used to define multiple variables

```
int[] array1, array2;
```

Will define two arrays.

```
int array1[], i;
```

Will define an array and a variable.

Comment: I'd argue that `int array1[], i;` is ugly, as it's declaring variables with two different types.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical difference between the two. I've never seen a style guide that prescribed or preferred the style in your first example. I've also never seen open source Java code that used the style in your first example. It's *always* `int[] array`.

Answer (score 0):

`int[] array` makes more sense to me because `int[]` is the type and `array` is the name.  It makes more sense to keep these separate and standardized.