# Object[] variableName; vs Object variableName[];

Tags: java, arrays, object

Working in `Java`, what is the difference between using

```
Object[] variableName;
```

and using:

```
Object variableName[];
```

Does it have the exact same effect on compilation and run? Or is there a difference?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array   (They're the same)

Comment: It is the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both statements are entirely equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The statements will compile to the same code, **BUT** if you write

`Type[] name` instead of `Type name[]` the code becomes more readable, because you always can see the type (Array or Not-Array) in front of the variable name. (In fact this is some kind of  my ppersonal meaning)

Answer (score 1):

From Java language specification (for Java 7) :

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the
>   declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable,
>   or both.

So yes, they are both equivalent and you can even mix the two styles in the same declaration (although the specification gives a healthy reminder to us that that tends to get ugly and confusing).