# Why does Java allow both int x[] and int[] x?

Tags: java, c, arrays

NOTE: this question was previously marked as a duplicate. It's subtly different, though: the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array) asked what the difference is between the two syntaxes; whereas I know there's no difference in meaning, and I'm asking in that case why Java allows both.

Why does Java allow both

```
int x[];
```

and

```
int[] x;
```

when I declare an array?

The latter makes much more sense: the variable is called `x`, not `x[]`, and its type is `int[]`, not `int`. Why not just enforce this? Allowing two different syntaxes seems just to invite confusion and inconsistency. It even appears to make it possible to declare a two-dimensional array as

```
int[] x[];
```

which is bordering on unreadable.

Is it something borrowed from C? (Why would C do it that way round, anyway?)

Comment: @user3386109 Read the last paragraph.

Comment: yeah, I just did. C doesn't allow that.

Comment: C does it so because `x[i]` is `int`.

Comment: @user3386109 Well, C forces you to use `int x[]`. Therefore if you want a language which lets you use both the C style and the arguably more sane `int[] x`, then you are where Java is. I make no comment on whether this was a good design decision or not.

Comment: @ericbn thanks for the pointer to the similar question! Mine isn't queer the same, though: that was asking what the difference is, whereas I know there's no difference, and I'm asking why in that case both are allowed.

Comment: @BlueMoon I've edited the question to explain why I think it's a subtly different question.

Comment: @ericbn er, obviously I meant "quite" rather than "queer"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least from specification there is no explicit reason for the existence of both. However as follows both ways provide a certain flexibility. With one variable both declarations will provide you with an int array.

x and y are both arrays when:

```
int[] x, y;
```

x is an array and y not when:

```
int x[], y;
```

See also [Oracle Java7 reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html). They also say that mixed notation is not recommended noting done the following example:

```
float[][] f[][], g[][][], h[];  // Yechh!
```

Answer (score 2):

It was added to help C programmers get used to Java.

In Java `int[] x;` is the preffered way.

Comment: OK. It seems a bad idea to help C programmers get used to Java by helping them write bad Java...

Comment: I agree, but such is Java. ;)

Comment: @chiastic-security Since the C way follows use and the Java-preferred way doesn't, I think exactly the opposite.

Comment: @o11c But the C way mixes type and instance declarations. It is a very broken and counter intuitive syntax. It is a pity Java adopted it.