# What is the difference between String name[] = {}; and String [] name = {};

Tags: java

i wrote this code in java and i was thinking about what's the difference between making this: `String [] whatever` and `String whatever []`, if someone could told me what's happening, it's better use `String [] whatever` = {} or use `String whatever[]` = {} or this it's just deprecated.

```
public class Snippet136 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        String names[] = {"Jhonny", "Edurardo", "Francis", "Franklin", "Freedy"};
        String [] eyes_colors = { "blue", "red", "black", "green", "black"};

        System.out.print("Names:");
        for (String name: names) {
            System.out.print( " " + name );
        }

        System.out.print("\n\nEyes colors:");
        for ( String eyes_color: eyes_colors ) {
            System.out.print( " " + eyes_color );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between int\[\] array and int array\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing whatsoever: the two forms are identical.

`String[] var` is more natural, and generally preferred (since it more logically combines the array type with the type name). `String var[]` is in Java basically because C/C++ use that syntax, and so it is a kind of "syntax compatibility".

Note that the postfix `[]` leads to some really insane syntax features, such as the ability to write `int function()[] { return null; }`: a function returning an `int[]`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is difference:

Only arrays:

```
String[] arr1, arr2;
```

Not just arrays:

```
String arr1[], str1, arr2[], str2;
```