# Using static array

Tags: java

I am novice programming. I am using java. I have declared an array like this:

```
static String horario[];
```

later, in one method I want to use this array like this:

```
if(datos.get(z+3).contains("CET")) {
    horario[]=  (datos.get(z+3).split("CET"));
    mipartido.setHorario(horario[0]);
}
```

but it says that `horario` cannot be resolved to a type.

How can I use this variable?

Comment: What do you think `horario[]=...` should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: you are declaring the array incorrectly. you should declare it as `Srting[] horario`. also when assigning it a value, use `horario = ` instead of `horario[] =`     EDIT: as @SotiriosDelimanolis pointed out below, this comment is incorrect.

Comment: @DavisBroda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis correction noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `[]` unless you're assigning an element to a specific index of the array, for example: `horario[0] = "abc";`

So, since you're assigning the array, you should change:

```
horario[]=  (datos.get(z+3).split("CET"));
```

to:

```
horario =  (datos.get(z+3).split("CET"));
```