# What is the difference between 'Object[] someThing' and 'Object someThing[]' if any?

Tags: java

Often in java code I see people declaring arrays in 2 different ways.

Sometimes it is

```
Object[] someObjectArray = new Object[...];
```

And other times I see

```
Object someObjectArray[] = new Object[...];
```

I have always used the first one.

I have tried googling this, but I cant seem to word the question correctly, so is there any difference, and of so, how are the two used differently?

Comment: See [*Difference between int\[\] array and int array\[\]*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

Comment: Okay, I hadn't come across that when looking for an answer. Thanks.