# arrays with in a method

Tags: java, arrays, swing, methods

So I have a code that is suppose to make labels and it seems to be almost working the only problem is that when it ask for user input the 7 questions (arrays) that is ask repeat.  And they only repeat on the first round.  Sorry its hard to explain. If you have any suggestions appreciate it.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Mail
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

                String nameAddressArray[] = getLabelData();
                String numBoxesInput;
                int numBoxes;
                String enterAnother = "Y";
                int counter;


                getLabelData();

                numBoxesInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of boxes in the order:");
                numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesInput);


                while(enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {
                    counter = 1;
                    // begin the inner loop to display a label and increment the counter
                    while(counter <= numBoxes)
                    {
                        System.out.println(nameAddressArray[0] + " " + nameAddressArray[1] + " " + nameAddressArray[2]);
                        System.out.println(nameAddressArray[3]);
                        System.out.println(nameAddressArray[4] + ", " + nameAddressArray[5] + " " + nameAddressArray[6]);
                        System.out.println("Box " + counter + " of " + numBoxes);
                        System.out.println();
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    } // end while

                    enterAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to produce more labels? Y or N");

                    while (!enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                    {
                        enterAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid Response. Please enter Y or N.",
                                                                    "DATA ENTRY ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }

                    if(enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                    {

                        getLabelData();

                        numBoxesInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of boxes in the order:");
                        numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesInput);
                    } // end if
                } // end while

            System.exit(0);
}

public static String[] getLabelData() {
    String[] nameAddressArray = new String[7];
    nameAddressArray[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter title (Mr., Ms., Dr., "
            + "etc.): ");
    nameAddressArray[1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name: ");
    nameAddressArray[2] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter lastname: ");
    nameAddressArray[3] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter street address: ");
    nameAddressArray[4] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter city: ");
    nameAddressArray[5] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter state (IL, MO, etc.): ");
    nameAddressArray[6] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter zip (e.g., 62025): ");
    return nameAddressArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want the whole process to repeat while they answer "Y", correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `getLabelData()` twice, once as:

```
String nameAddressArray[] = getLabelData();
```

and then later as:

```
getLabelData();
```

Remove the second call.

Apart from that, as has been pointed out in [Gi0rgi0s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989110/2191154) answer, having the array brackets following the variable type instead of the name is considered [better style and less confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/129188/2191154), meaning your line should preferably be

```
String[] nameAddressArray = getLabelData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String nameAddressArray[] = getLabelData();
```

to just

```
String[] nameAddressArray;
```

You are calling it twice.

Comment: It will compile, but I understand your way is preferred. I will change it.

Comment: I just looked it up. Learned something new today :) Still keeping the downvote, though, since I don't think this is a full answer...