# Explain variable declaration this way

Tags: java, variables

```
public class PassByReference {
    int oneTozero (int arg[]) {
    }
}
```

I've never seen a variable declared this way. Can someone explain? Thanks

Comment: class = `PassByReference`  method = `oneTozero`  arguments = `int arg[]`

Comment: Do you mean why it's defined in one line?

Comment: This is a method declaration.

Comment: That's because it isn't a variable declaration.

Comment: To clarify: I assume your question is about the method parameter -- the `int arg[]` part?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a variable, you have a class called  `PassByReference` with method type integer `oneTozero` and an integer array as an argument to that method `arg[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If the confusion is about `int arg[]` vs `int[] arg`, that is an [alternative syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129178/14955) to specify arrays for people coming from C.

It means the same thing.

And, yes, it's confusing, especially if you mix the two `int[] twoDim[]`.

Answer (score 0):

`int oneTozero (int arg[]) {}` describe the method.
 `int arg[]` is an parameter. It is an array of int. In Java there are at least 3 ways to describe parameter as an array and all of them are equal:

- `int array[]`
- `int[] array`
- `int... array`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PassByReference {
    int oneTozero (int arg[]) {
    }
}
```

New class `PassByReference` with `public` visibility is been declared. This class contains `oneTozero` method with `default` visibility and array of integer as argument.