# Difference between [ ] before and after the variable name

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax

I'm playing around with 2-Dimensional arrays in Java a bit and i just cant seem to find a difference between those two ways of initializing a 2-Dimensional Array.

```
//Option one
int field[][] = new int[n][n];

//Option two
int[][] field = new int[n][n];
```

Comment: They are equivalent. The second syntax is preferred, the first one is almost never seen. Note you can also do `int[] field[] =` for a 2d array...

Comment: Thanks for the edit by the way, very kind of you! :-)

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array

Answer (score 4):

They are both legal ways to declare arrays, and carry the same meaning. However, the first form is discouraged, since, as [Java's tutorial states it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html): "However, convention discourages this form; the brackets identify the array type and should appear with the type designation.".

Comment: Plus it may raises a linter alert. Sonar will tell you that it's a C form declaration for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find a difference because it's the same. Java allows you to place the brackets after the variable type or name, it's the same.

Although, by convention, it's better to place after the type and not the name (so it's easier to see the that this is an array)

source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html